# Tomcat running from command prompt but shows 404 Error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

My tomcat is not working in eclipse but running from terminal. i found this wierd, so i checked with a new tomcat installation. I created a new tomcat (extracted .zip downloaded form apache website) created a new workspace and created a new server to check if the problem is with the old tomcat. To my surprise, new server in new workspace fails too. If i run from command line, its working fine. But from eclipse, the server is started but i am getting a 404 resource not found error. [image: Eclipse console output is here]

Dont just cross out this as a basic question and help me out. I am stuck because of this and am unable to find any solution on net.

Comment: maybe you should post the Tomcat settings

Comment: I changed the old tomcat settings. But for new tomcat in new workspace, i just extracted the zip i downloaded from website. Its completely fresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Resolved

I did this:[image]

Previously it was using workspace metadata. I changed it to tomcat installation data. I guess there was some leftover stale data from previous installation. Took too long to figure this out.